# Brazil: the Once and Future Country - how do you understand the word "once"?

Tags: grammar

This is the title of a book.

> **Brazil: the Once and Future Country**

How should I understand the word **once** in that line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a reference to the English legend of King Arthur.  Traditionally referred to as the Once and Future King.  *Rex Quondam Rex Futurum*.  The phrase was used in the works of Sir Thomas Malory in the 15th Century.

The legend has it that the former King - he who was once king - will rise and rule again in England's hour of need.

The phrase *once and future* is often used to describe something that was once great and will be so again.